# What characters are allowed in jQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery, firefox

I'm am using jQuery to smooth scroll to some anchors on my website. The anchors are created programmatically so that they can contain some german umlauts like »ü, ä, ö« or other unicode characters like »ß,è« etc..
The function uses the hash to select the element the hash is referring to:

```
// Smooth scroll to anchor position.
function smoothScroll (hash) {

  var scrollTo = typeof $(hash).offset().top != undefined ? $(hash).offset().top: 0;

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: scrollTo

  }, 800);
}

// Test smooth scroll.
smoothScroll ("#Akademie-für-Gestaltung");
```

This works in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox. It produces the following error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #Akademie-f%C3%BCr-Gestaltung...
```

This brings me to my question. How do I know, which characters are allowed in jQuery selectors? The [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) mentions only the following characters `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^{|}~`

And how do I have to escape other characters, to make sure the selectors will work in all modern browser?

Comment: `-` is a meta character. You have to escape it while using it as a selector.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: No, you do not need to escape a `-` in CSS selectors.

Comment: _“How do I know, which characters are allowed in jQuery selectors? ”_ – first of all, you check the jQuery docs. https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Since you have free input data, I'd just stop caring and simply escape everything.

Comment: I did, but doesn't say anything about umlauts. It mentions only `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~`

Comment: @CBroe Yup. Just saw that doc. `-` is not a part of the meta characters.

Comment: _“but doesn't say anything about umlauts”_ – the umlauts aren’t the problem here - the URL-encoding in `f%C3%BCr` is.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but then Firefox did the encoding, because I passed the hash unencodet...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I know, which characters are allowed in jQuery selectors?

They're CSS selectors. All the details are in [the selectors specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/). The rules for literal IDs and class names used in selectors are [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). Escaping lets you use characters you couldn't use literally (but it's a pain, so best to avoid). So for instance, while you can use `ü`, doing so is a pain because you can't use it literally, you have to escape it.

But ID selectors are just a special (quite fast) kind of selector. You can use an [attribute selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation) in quotes, which means you can avoid escaping: `$('[id="Akademie-f%C3%BCr-Gestaltung"]')` That's perfectly valid and correct.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I found out, that it works also, if i avoid jQuery but use `document.getElementById(hash)`. So the problem has to do how jQuery handles the selectors? I like your work around!

Comment: @user5950: No, it's just that `getElementById` doesn't take a selector, it takes an ID, so there's no issue. But a CSS ID selector (`#foo`) is a special thing with only a small set of allowed characters that you can use without escaping. You might give yourself a handy utility function: `$.gid = function(id) { var e = document.getElementById(id); return e ? $(e) : $(); };` Then: `$.gid("Akademie-f%C3%BCr-Gestaltung").show();` or similar. That way, you get the speed of `getElementById` without worrying about the contents of the ID.